# Problems with preparing Json string to pass in WCF service.

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, wcf

I'm trying to communicate between javascript application with a WCF service. The WCF Service I created provide the following method:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/ExportToXml")]
    void ExportToXml(List<Span> spans, List<Detection> detections);

    [DataContract]
    public class Detection
    {
       [DataMember]
       public int TID { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
       public double Longitude { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
       public double Latitude { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
       public double Height { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
       public int SN { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
       public string TLine_Name { get; set; }
  }

  [DataContract]
  public class Span
  {
       [DataMember]
       public int SN { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
       public double Longitude { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
       public double Latitude { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
       public string TLine_Name { get; set; }
   }
```

However, I am having trouble preparing the json to pass into this function on the js client side. The json that i prepared has the form:

```
var input = {
              "spans": [{
                  "SN": 1,
                  "Longitude": 1000000,
                  "Latitude": 1000000,
                  "TLine_Name": "Circuit Test 1"
              }, {
                  "SN": 2,
                  "Longitude": 2000000,
                  "Latitude": 2000000,
                  "TLine_Name": "Circuit Test 2"
              }],

              "detections": [{
                  "TID": 1,
                  "Longitude": 1000000,
                  "Latitude": 1000000,
                  "Height": 15,
                  "SN": 1,
                  "TLine_Name": "Circuit Test 1"
              }, {
                  "TID": 2,
                  "Longitude": 1000000,
                  "Latitude": 1000000,
                  "Height": 12,
                  "SN": 1,
                  "TLine_Name": "Circuit Test 1"
              }, {
                  "TID": 3,
                  "Longitude": 1000000,
                  "Latitude": 1000000,
                  "Height": 14,
                  "SN": 1,
                  "TLine_Name": "Circuit Test 1"
              }, {
                  "TID": 4,
                  "Longitude": 1000000,
                  "Latitude": 1000000,
                  "Height": 10,
                  "SN": 2,
                  "TLine_Name": "Circuit Test 2"
              }, {
                  "TID": 5,
                  "Longitude": 1000000,
                  "Latitude": 1000000,
                  "Height": 8,
                  "SN": 2,
                  "TLine_Name": "Circuit Test 2"
              }]
          };
```

The service doesn't like the above json input. Any help on this matter is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can send the JSON object to the service running on my own machine. Therefore it is not the format of the JSON object that is being sent to the service which is the problem. You have another problem. More details about the client might help solve what it is.

I understand that your client is a JavaScript application, but here is my C# client which successfully sends the JSON object to the service:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:9001/WCFServices/RestfulService/ExportToXml");
request.ContentType = "text/json";
request.Method = "POST";
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = @"{ ""spans"": " + 
        @"[{ ""SN"": 1, ""Longitude"": 1000000,""Latitude"": 1000000,""TLine_Name"": ""Circuit Test 1""}, " +
        @"{""SN"": 2, ""Longitude"": 2000000, ""Latitude"": 2000000, ""TLine_Name"": ""Circuit Test 2"" }]," + 
        @"""detections"": " +
        @"[{ ""TID"": 1, ""Longitude"": 1000000, ""Latitude"": 1000000, ""Height"": 15,""SN"": 1, ""TLine_Name"": ""Circuit Test 1"" }, " + 
        @"{ ""TID"": 2, ""Longitude"": 1000000, ""Latitude"": 1000000, ""Height"": 12, ""SN"": 1, ""TLine_Name"": ""Circuit Test 1"" }, " +
        @"{ ""TID"": 3, ""Longitude"": 1000000, ""Latitude"": 1000000, ""Height"": 14, ""SN"": 1, ""TLine_Name"": ""Circuit Test 1"" }, " +
        @"{ ""TID"": 4, ""Longitude"": 1000000, ""Latitude"": 1000000, ""Height"": 10, ""SN"": 2, ""TLine_Name"": ""Circuit Test 2"" }, " +
        @"{ ""TID"": 5, ""Longitude"": 1000000, ""Latitude"": 1000000, ""Height"": 8, ""SN"": 1, ""TLine_Name"": ""Circuit Test 2"" }] }";
   streamWriter.Write(json);
}
WebResponse ws = request.GetResponse();
Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(ws.GetResponseStream());
string response = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
responseStream.Close();
```